# React and OpenSeadragon draw polygons on image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, openseadragon

I'm writing my web-app with [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/) and I want to create a viewer to render an image and create multiple **editable polygons** on it.

[OpenSeadragon](https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon) is perfect for this job, in particular there is a useful plugin [OpenseadragonFabricjsOverlay](https://github.com/altert/OpenseadragonFabricjsOverlay) that use fabric.js.

So after I installed the following libraries:

```
"@types/fabric": "^4.5.12",
"@types/openseadragon": "^3.0.4",
"fabric": "^5.2.4",
"openseadragon": "^3.1.0",
"openseadragon-fabricjs-overlay": "github:altert/OpenseadragonFabricjsOverlay"
```

and created `Viewer component`

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import OpenSeadragon from 'openseadragon';
import 'openseadragon-fabricjs-overlay';
import { fabric } from 'fabric';

const Viewer = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const viewer = OpenSeadragon({
      id: 'osd-viewer',
      tileSources: {
        type: 'image',
        url: 'path/to/image/jpg'
      }
    });

    // Initialize overlay
    const options = {
        scale: 1000
    }
    const overlay = viewer.fabricjsOverlay(options);

    return () => {
      viewer.destroy();
    };
  });

  return (
    <div id="osd-viewer" style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}></div>
  );
};

export default Viewer;
```

I get that error:
**[openseadragon-canvas-overlay] requires OpenSeadragon**

This occurs because OpenSeaDragon has not yet loaded.

How can I include the `openseadragon-fabricjs-overlay.js` file after OpenSeadragon?
Do you have advices?

**UPDATE**:
Follow this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4281) to fix it

Answer (score 0):

The fabric overlay is assuming that OpenSeadragon will be found on the global `window` object. You might be able to fix it by adding this between the OSD and plugin imports:

```
window.OpenSeadragon = OpenSeadragon;
```